# Can ServiceStack mimic a WCF response?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, servicestack

I'm trialling out ServiceStack and loving what I'm seeing so far. However I've run into a bit of a brick wall.

I have a system retrieving data from another system via web services - a service at both ends. These two systems are from different vendors - so I have no control over changing them - and are configured to talk to each other via WCF web services. Let's say "Lemon" calls "Orange" to get some information about a customer.

The way we implement these two systems is slightly different to what the vendors planned - we point their service configuration to our intermediary service - let's call it "Peach" - which goes off and does some other things before returning the information. For example, "Lemon" calls what it thinks is "Orange" but is actually our intermediary service "Peach" using the same method names. "Peach" calls "Orange" for the customer information and for example overrides the email address for the customer with something else before combining all the information appropriately and returning it to "Lemon" in the format it was expecting.

I would like to get "Peach" using ServiceStack. However it's responses needs to be **identical** to a WCF service returning via wsHttpBinding. Is this possible with ServiceStack? Would it involve overriding the Soap 1.2 type?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ServiceStack's built-in [SOAP Support](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support) doesn't return the response you're after, you may need to return the exact SOAP response you're after as a raw `string`.

#### Raw Access to WCF SOAP Message

To access the WCF's Raw Request in your Service you can use the `IRequiresSoapMessage` interface to tell ServiceStack to skip de-serialization of the request and instead pass the raw WCF Message to the Service instead for manual processing, e.g:

```
public class RawWcfMessage : IRequiresSoapMessage {
    public Message Message { get; set; }
}

public class MyServices : Service
{
    public object Post(RawWcfMessage request) { 
        var requestMsg = request.Message... //Raw WCF SOAP Message
    }
}
```

#### Creating custom WCF Response

Some level of customization is possible by creating a custom WCF Message response and returning the raw output as a string, e.g:

```
var wcfResponse = wcfServiceProxy.GetPeach(...);

var responseMsg = Message.CreateMessage(
   MessageVersion.Soap12, "urn:GetPeach", wcfResponse);

return responseMsg.ToString();
```

Otherwise you may need to use a HTTP Client like [Http Utils](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Http-Utils) to POST raw SOAP to the WCF Service and return the raw string Response.

Comment: Awesome... And thanks for your quick response. Things are looking "peachy" now. Is there anything that ServiceStack can't do? :)

Answer (score 0):

This question isn't specifically related to WCF. What WCF returns is not a construct of WCF, it is returning a standards based response as specified by the WS* standards. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_service_specifications lists many of the standards.

Your question isn't specifically making ServiceStack emulate WCF, it is for ServiceStack to return responses adhering to existing published standards. Standards that WCF has already built in with the WsHttpBinding configuration.

Comment: No his question is specifically how to return an **identical** response as an existing WCF Service. ServiceStack's SOAP endpoints already return a valid SOAP response, which has nothing to do if it's exactly what the existing generated WCF client proxies expect or not.

Comment: @mythz that's still missing the point. He is not attempting to return a response identical to a WCF service, he's attempting to return a response that is identical to the WS* standards applicable to that service. It might seem like I'm being pedantic but this is a very important aspect, he should not be looking at WCF. He should be looking at the WS* standards he needs to return.

Comment: No you're missing the point, he's not trying to return **any** valid WS-* response (which ServiceStack SOAP endpoints already provide for free) his question is exactly what he's specifically asking: **However it's responses needs to be identical to a WCF service** - and not whatever else you're assuming he means.

Comment: @mythz if he returns the correctly formatted response for the applicable WS* standards, it will be identical to the WCF service response. WCF WsHttpBinding is not some adhoc creation, it returns responses as the standards dictates, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Well that sounds all great in theory but not true in practice. All valid SOAP responses are not identical with each other and Generated WCF proxies are fragile where even different namespaces can break existing clients.

Comment: I can't attest to code created by the proxy generator, that generator is just a big ball of problems that doesn't serve any purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the debate on my behalf! I see what you're saying Chris but all standards aside I just need it to exactly replicate the WCF service. I deliberately left all mention of WS-* standards out of my question because the heart of the issue is not really meeting a standard, but forcing a response into a different format.